# How to redirect app's data stream to browser in real time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, apache-kafka

My [node app](https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node) can read stream from [kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#quickstart_download) producer and console.log it to terminal in real time. But I would like to update it in my web app the same way (real time). How can I implement it?

I start my app with 'node index.js' command (or npm start).

**index.js:**

```
  'use strict';
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server,
    data = [];
...

consumer.on('message', function (message) {
    console.log(message);
    data.push(message);
    //global.location.reload();
});

...

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send(data);
});

server = app.listen(3002, function(){
    console.log('Listening on port 3002');
});
```

I think, that I need modify `res.send(data)` or add some code to `on('message')` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep connection between client and server.
Try this [socket.io](http://socket.io/) package to update message in realtime.